# Left Join Translate to Inner join in Linq

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have two tables :

`ProductCodes`:

```
Code             Year             PageNo
-----------------------------------------
```

and `Costs` :

```
Code             Year         City         QsNo            price
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want To preserve All code in specific `year-pageNo` and then show costs for specific `year-city-Qsno`(If exists) and for costs that don't exist I return null.

I wrote this query:

```
var Result = from code in ent.ProductCodes
                         join cost in ent.Costs
                           on new { a = code.Year, b = code.Code } equals new { a = cost.Year, b = cost.Code }
                           into AllCosts
                         from OutPut in AllCosts.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where code.PageNo == PageNo && OutPut.Year == Year && OutPut.City == City && OutPut.QsNo == Qsno
                         select new
                         {
                             ProductCode = code.Code
                             Col6 = OutPut.Price
                         };
```

but it convert to `INNER JOIN`.Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're checking the Year, City, and QsNo on the `OutPut` variable after the join... but if OutPut is null (which would happen if there are no rows in AllCosts) then these checks will always be false, so the pair (code, OutPut) will be filtered out by the where clause. EF detects this fact and generates a query which is more efficient by just using an inner join.

What you really want to do is filter out candidate rows from Costs, rather than filtering on (code, cost) pairs. To do this you can move your filter up, so it applies directly to the Costs table:

```
var Result = from code in ent.ProductCodes
                     join cost 
                       in ent.Costs.Where(c => c.Year == Year && c.City == City && c.QsNo == Qsno)
                       on new { code.Year, code.Code } equals new { cost.Year, cost.Code }
                       into AllCosts
                     from OutPut in AllCosts.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where code.PageNo == PageNo
                     select new
                     {
                         ProductCode = code.Code
                         Col6 = OutPut.Price
                     };
```