# Multiple Left Join and Inner Join with LinQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this SQL code who works:

```
SELECT 
    FF.numero, 
    FF.cuo_pla, 
    FF.num_pla,
    PN.Descripcion,
    TN.Nombre
FROM encf EF
JOIN forf FF
    ON EF.numero = FF.numero 
    AND EF.[manual] = FF.[manual]
    AND EF.comproba = FF.comproba
    AND EF.tipo_fac = FF.tipo_fac
    AND EF.sucursal = FF.sucursal
LEFT JOIN Planes PN
    ON FF.num_pla = PN.Numero
LEFT JOIN Tarjetas TN
    ON PN.IdTarjeta = TN.ID
WHERE 
    EF.documento = 123456789
```

There are two LEFT JOIN and one INNER JOIN. I know how to do the inner join but don't know how to make that two left join who need an id obtained in the first inner join. I'm making something like this:

```
var queryEncFor = from enc in db.encf
                              join forF in db.forf on
                                new
                                {
                                    JoinProperty1 = enc.numero,
                                    JoinProperty2 = enc.manual,
                                    JoinProperty3 = enc.comproba,
                                    JoinProperty4 = enc.tipo_fac,
                                    JoinProperty5 = enc.sucursal
                                }
                                equals
                                new
                                {
                                    JoinProperty1 = forFact.numero,
                                    JoinProperty2 = forFact.manual,
                                    JoinProperty3 = forFact.comproba,
                                    JoinProperty4 = forFact.tipo_fac,
                                    JoinProperty5 = forFact.sucursal
                                }
                              where enc.documento == doc
                              select new UnionEncForFact
                              {
                                  numero = enc.numero,
                                  cuo_pla = forF.cuo_pla == null ? 0 : forF.cuo_pla.Value,
                                  num_pla = forF.num_pla
                              };
```

The inner join its working  but I don't know how to translate the two left join, any suggestion?

Comment: Does this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812990/left-join-translate-to-inner-join-in-linq) address your issue?

Comment: Try to use navigation properties instead of joins. Seems to me that that should at least be possible for the left joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins), the query will be :

```
var queryEncFor = (from enc in db.encf
                   join forF in db.forf on
                   new
                   {
                       enc.numero,
                       enc.manual,
                       enc.comproba,
                       enc.tipo_fac,
                       enc.sucursal
                   }
                   equals
                   new
                   {
                       forF.numero,
                       forF.manual,
                       forF.comproba,
                       forF.tipo_fac,
                       forF.sucursal
                   }
                   join plane in db.Planes on forF.num_pla equals plane.Numero into leftedPlanes
                   from leftedPlane in leftedPlanes.DefaultIfEmpty()

                   join tarjeta in db.Tarjetas on leftedPlane?.IdTarjeta equals tarjeta.ID into leftedTarjetas
                   from leftedTarjeta in leftedTarjetas.DefaultIfEmpty()

                   where enc.documento == 1
                   select new UnionEncForFact
                   {
                       numero = enc.numero,
                       cuo_pla = forF.cuo_pla == null ? 0 : forF.cuo_pla.Value,
                       num_pla = forF.num_pla,
                       Descripcion = leftedPlane?.Descripcion,
                       Nombre = leftedTarjeta?.Nombre ?? 0
                   }).ToList();
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Hi Sajid! I have a problem with your solution, when I try to use the variable **plane** after declare it, give me a error that says "The name "plane" does not exist in the current context". So I can't use in the left join of Tarjetas and in the select of Description. You know what may be happening? Ty for the answer.